# Deploy angular app in multiple virtual directory

Tags: angular, iis, deployment, virtual-directory

I am creating an angular app. I want to deploy this application in separate application like  below.

Means, URL for the clients as below but all pointing to the same folder "c:\angularapp"

- clientA --> www.abc.com\clientA
- clientB --> www.abc.com\clientB
- clientP --> www.xyz.com\clientP
- clientQ --> www.xyz.com\clientQ

Based on clients I am displaying pages differently.

As I know, while deploy we need to setup base-href but in the above scenario. what is the option?

Is it possible to do deploy like above? if yes how?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could host the application like below:

site: abc

application-> clientA

in the application use the file path to "c:\angularapp".

and then use the below URL rewrite rule to set the base path on the site.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="base test">
                    <match filterByTags="Base" pattern="/" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="/clientA/" />
                </rule>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

set the rule at the application level.

do the same thing for the site and application.